# Configuring CAS for Database Audits

Tags: spring, cas

I'm trying to save the cas audits to a postgres database. For whatever reason, CAS is trying to use the hsqldb driver, even though I've specified the postgres driver.

I'm using a CAS 6.0.3 docker image built with the cas-overlay-template project.

Here is my configuration:

```
cas.audit.jdbc.driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
cas.audit.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/cas_audits
cas.audit.jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
cas.audit.jdbc.user=someuser
cas.audit.jdbc.password=somepassword
```

I've included the cas server support for jdbc audits in the grade build file.

```
compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-audit-jdbc:${casServerVersion}"
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    | 2019-05-02 20:54:40,568 WARN [com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource] - <Registered driver with driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.>
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    | 2019-05-02 20:54:41,127 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/cas].[dispatcherServlet]] - <Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/cas] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT AUD_DATE FROM COM_AUDIT_TRAIL WHERE AUD_CLIENT_IP = ? AND AUD_USER = ? AND AUD_ACTION = ? AND APPLIC_CD = ? AND AUD_DATE >= ? ORDER BY AUD_DATE DESC]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: COM_AUDIT_TRAIL in statement [SELECT AUD_DATE FROM COM_AUDIT_TRAIL WHERE AUD_CLIENT_IP = ? AND AUD_USER = ? AND AUD_ACTION = ? AND APPLIC_CD = ? AND AUD_DATE >= ? ORDER BY AUD_DATE DESC]] with root cause>
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    | org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: COM_AUDIT_TRAIL
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:311) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1557) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:706) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:758) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apereo.cas.web.support.JdbcThrottledSubmissionHandlerInterceptorAdapter.exceedsThreshold(JdbcThrottledSubmissionHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java:55) ~[cas-server-support-throttle-jdbc-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apereo.cas.web.support.AbstractThrottledSubmissionHandlerInterceptorAdapter.preHandle(AbstractThrottledSubmissionHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java:83) ~[cas-server-support-throttle-core-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:246) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:494) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy208.preHandle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1033) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apereo.cas.web.support.AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.java:28) ~[cas-server-core-web-api-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apereo.cas.security.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:261) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.4.jar!/:2.0.10.4]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apereo.cas.security.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:240) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.4.jar!/:2.0.10.4]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apereo.cas.security.AddResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(AddResponseHeadersFilter.java:94) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.4.jar!/:2.0.10.4]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apereo.cas.logging.web.ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.doFilter(ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.java:98) ~[cas-server-core-logging-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apereo.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:66) ~[inspektr-common-1.8.4.GA.jar!/:1.8.4.GA]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

The first line : `Registered driver with driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation` makes me think that my config settings for the driverClass aren't being registered.

Please let me know if I can add any additional information to help get to the bottom of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Apart from audits, have you defined another property which has been picked up for sure?

Comment: Could you share a sample repo to reproduce the problem? The exception is too broad.

Comment: @leopal Yes, the weird thing is that I can successfully use postgres for authentication

Comment: Have you tried, Francesc Recio answer below?

Comment: @leopal yes, I did and I get the same error

Comment: Maybe you should provide a sample repo reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the trace of error:

```
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    | 2019-05-02 20:54:40,568 WARN [com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource] - <Registered driver with driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.>
aod_cas.1.kblf4acydbtx@ptzolov-leader    | 2019-05-02 20:54:41,127 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/cas].[dispatcherServlet]] - <Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/cas] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is ...
```

The error shows you that the environment tries to handle the data source with **com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource**. This happens because the new versions of **Spring Jpa** use **Hikari** as the data source by default and ignore the CAS properties.

I would add to the **application.properties** configuration:

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource 

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/cas_audits
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=someuser
spring.datasource.password=somepassword

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
```

Because CAS delegates it to Spring.

Comment: Put also `spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`

Comment: That didn't work either..I still get the same thing. It must be some default value overriding my configuration, but I can't figure out why that's happening. Is there some other configuration file I should be using? Currently I'm using the cas.properties file

Comment: Spring by default use application.properties in src/main/resources, try to create that file and put the above configuration

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this issue is that your settings are not put in a file that CAS recognizes, or that the file is misplaced. You do not need to modify your application.properties file or change anything with Spring JPA.

If you examine your logs, you'll find something that is similar to:

```
INFO <Configuration files found at [/etc/cas/config] are 
[[file [/etc/cas/config/application.yml], file [/etc/cas/config/cas.properties]...
```

Which means at the very least, your settings need to be put into `/etc/cas/config/cas.properties`. Note how the path refers to `/etc`.

Otherwise, assuming your settings are in the right place and you have that module, CAS will try to connect to that database URL. For example, if I run the same setup as you, I'd see the following in logs:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
```

...which tell me that CAS recognized my settings, tried to connect to the database and failed (which makes sense as I have no postgres database running)

So examine logs, and make sure your settings are in the right place. More at https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/installation/Troubleshooting-Guide.html#review-logs

Comment: I can see that it's picking up the correct properties file, and I know it is actually picking it up because I have other config there that gets set correctly.

Comment: You can pick up the other configuration file but your log indicates that it also tries to pick up the datasource that handles spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar problem like yours. I am using CAS 6.1 with docker deployment.

```
2020-09-28 16:28:14,837 WARN [com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource] - <Registered driver with driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.>
```

I add JDBC Audit and **also Throttling Authentication using JDBC** in the grade build file.

It turns out the problem was the Throttling Authentication. I did not use the right configuration key. The right configuration key for throttling using JDBC is **cas.authn.throttle.jdbc**

So, the reason why hikari use hsqldb, because the default values are not overwritten in our cas.properties. You need to find the right configuration key.

```
cas.authn.throttle.jdbc.url=${cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].url}
cas.authn.throttle.jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
cas.authn.throttle.jdbc.user=${cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].user}
cas.authn.throttle.jdbc.password=${cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].password}
```